# htmlspecialchars is not working as I want! I want < to be gt, NOT &gt;

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace, htmlspecialchars

This is my input:

```
<
```

This is the output I need:

```
gt
```

But this is the output I GET from htmlspecialchars:

```
&gt;
```

Basically, I want htmlspecialchars result, but really stripped down. I only want characters `a-z` and `0-9`.

Can anyone help?

Comment: If you want something in your own format, you have to write it yourself. `htmlspecialchars` is for creating standard HTML entities.

Comment: I wonder if there's some [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) going on here. Why don't you want the standard HTML entity output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Just [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) all characters which aren't in `a-z0-9` with an empty string which you get from [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php))

```
<?php

    $str = "<";
    echo preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9]/", "", htmlentities($str));

?>
```

output:

```
lt
```

Comment: Hello, thanks, I tried this - nearly there! :) Just one problem - it converts & to amp... any solutions ?

Comment: @caustic This is what you wanted?! You said you want to remove everything expect: `a-z0-9` ?!

Comment: @caustic Well what pattern is then behind your replacement? What do you want to get replaced?

Comment: You gave me the perfect solution ... just one other thing I forgot to add. I want all occurrences of 'amp' to be removed. So I want lg instead of amplg. Your code gives me amplg. :)

Comment: @caustic Try: `/([^a-z0-9]|amp)/` as regex, is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to remove the `&` and `;`:

```
$result = preg_replace('/&(\w+);/', '$1', htmlspecialchars($string));
```